# Parsing command-line arguments similar to archlinux pacman

Tags: python, argparse

I'm creating a python script with usage in the same style as [`pacman`](http://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) in Arch Linux, summarized by:

```
prog <operation> [options] [targets]
```

- *operations* are of the form -X (hyphen, uppercase letter), and one is required when calling the script.
- *options* are of the form -x (hyphen, lowercase letter), and *can mean different things* for different operations.

For example:

- `pacman -Syu` means perform the `sync` operation with `refresh` and `sysupgrade` options, upgrading the entire system with fresh packages.
- `pacman -Qu` means perform the `query` operation with the `upgrades` option, listing all outdated packages.
- `pacman -Ss <arg>` means perform the `sync` operation with the `search` option, which expects another argument as the pattern to search for in the sync packages.

**The punchline:**

I've been looking into the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) library for python, trying to figure out how to implement this. I've run into some problems/design issues so far:

- `argparse` only accepts hyphen-prefixed arguments as optional arguments. All my "operations" would show up as optional arguments, when one is definitely required.
- I could make my script have one "positional"/required argument, which would be the operation (I would have to switch operations to words, like `upgrade` or `add`), followed by optional arguments. This, however, still wouldn't solve the same-option-symbol-working-differently issue, and also wouldn't let me easily list all the supported operations in the `--help` text.

What's the smoothest way to handle this argument parsing? I'm not against changing my command's usage, but as I said above, it doesn't seem to help my situation as far as I can tell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this [support for sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) buried in the argparse help. It's exactly what I need, with the only caveat being I am not using `-X` as the format for operations; I am just using words like `add` and `search` instead.

For completeness here's an example of using sub-parsers from the link above:

```
>>> # create the top-level parser
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "a" command
>>> parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
>>> parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')
>>>
>>> # create the parser for the "b" command
>>> parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
>>> parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')
>>>
>>> # parse some argument lists
>>> parser.parse_args(['a', '12'])
Namespace(bar=12, foo=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'b', '--baz', 'Z'])
Namespace(baz='Z', foo=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make `-S` and `-Q` part of a mutually exclusive option group with the `required` keyword argument set to `True`. This wouldn't enforce the requirement to make those the first arguments given, nor would it restrict which other options could be used with each. You'd have to enforce the latter after calling `parse_args`.

Another option I thought of was to make `-S` and `-Q` subcommands. Calling `add_parser` with a first argument starting with '-' seems to be legal, but the errors you get when you actually try to call your script makes me think that either the support is buggy/unintended, or that the error reporting is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option would be to use `getopt`: http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

Comment: From your link: "Note that an equivalent command line interface could be produced with less code and more informative help and error messages by using the `argparse` module..."

Comment: If you could prove how `getopt` is better than `argparse` in this case, that may be worth an accept.